# Laravel: Database connection error when using "config:cache", but working fine without caching

Tags: php, laravel

Now this is a really weird one.

My .env file is fine. When I run

```
php artisan config:clear
```

everything works. But when I run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

my database connection stops working:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'foobar'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
```

So again: My settings are correct. But when they are cached, they stop working. How could this possibly be?! Laravel seems to use some kind of old settings when using the cache, but I have no idea where these are coming from?

What I already tried:

- `php artisan optimize:clear`
- `rm -rf bootstrap/cache/*.php`

I ran into this issue while trying to setup a [Laravel forge deployment script for zero downtime](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/wqlgbg/comment/ikox2ib/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Comment: Is `foobar` the correct db user from your `.env` file? Maybe `source .env` before caching?

Comment: No, `foobar` isn't the correct one. That's the whole point: I don't know where `foobar` is coming from. Sorry, what exactly do you mean by "`source .env`"?

Comment: Run `source .env` to read the values from the `.env` file into your environment variables.

Comment: If all the values starting with `DB_*` in your `.env` file are correct, so it seems you have set some static values in the `/config/database.php` file.

Comment: better to run this following command with order: ````php artisan route:clear````, ````php artisan config:clear````, ````php artisan cache:clear````

Comment: @kodfire Definitely not. There are no static values there. I use the Laravel default configuration for that.

Comment: @mrobbizulfikar Doesn't work. As soon as I run `php artisan cache:config` after that the old wrong values are still being used for the database connection.

Comment: I assume you already searched your project and env variables for `foobar`?

Answer (score 0):

I hard coded the path to the ssl files for my database connection in `/config/database.php`. Changed that to use the values of `.env`, now it's working.